# How to put these 9 buttons in 3 rows and let them fit

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to 9 buttons in 3 rows in one layout. However, as some of the buttons contains more text than the others the buttons don't fit. Now it looks like this:

[image]

I tried to put each row in a `LinearLayout` with `weightSum = 3` but the rows disappear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#32c6a6"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/kontaktfrag">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="13 egenskaber"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Profeternes egenskaber"
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bøntider"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"/>
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wudu"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wudu's betingelser"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wudu's afbrydelser"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bønnens søjler"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bønnens betingelser"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bønnens afbrydelser"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout >
```

Have also tried to use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919089/how-to-put-9-buttons-in-3-rows-in-android-xml-layout), but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: You should indeed use a GridView. THEN and only then, as a secondary goal (not related to tihs), learn how to use weights.

Comment: TableLayout will work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#32c6a6"
    android:weightSum="3">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linRow1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3">
        <Button
            android:text="13 egenskaber"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:text="Profeternes egenskaber"
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:text="Bøntider"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linRow2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3">
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:text="Wudu"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:text="Wudu's betingelser"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:text="Wudu's afbrydelser"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linRow3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3">
        <Button
            android:text="Bønnens søjler"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:text="Bønnens betingelser"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:text="Bønnens afbrydelser"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Check this

Comment: What about the framelayout? You removed it, I need it :)

Comment: Next time put more details, this  answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/kontaktfrag">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:text="13 egenskaber"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:text="Profeternes egenskaber"
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:text="Bøntider"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"/>
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:text="Wudu"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:text="Wudu's betingelser"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:text="Wudu's afbrydelser"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:text="Bønnens søjler"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:text="Bønnens betingelser"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:text="Bønnens afbrydelser"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Look at this. Define every button in the same size.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#32c6a6"
android:orientation="vertical>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/kontaktfrag"
    android:weightSum="3">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="13 egenskaber"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Profeternes egenskaber"
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bøntider"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"/>
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wudu"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wudu's betingelser"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wudu's afbrydelser"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bønnens søjler"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bønnens betingelser"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bønnens afbrydelser"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout >
```