# Multi column listview layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

How to do a layout like this? I currently use a listActivity and I need the same experience with this kind of layout.
[image]

Comment: Try This [StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView)

Comment: Check https://github.com/huewu/PinterestLikeAdapterView..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Staggered Grid View](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/) library. Also check and [Quilt View](https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary). This is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

To get this effect, you should create two list views and link the scrolls of both lists.

Define a OnScrollListener on both listviews and when "onScroll()", move programatically the other list. I think if all images are cached you shouldn't have delays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Staggered Grid View library. But there you need to mention height of each image pragmatically to set height of list view. Else when you scroll to end and come back to top, the alignment of images on top will get disturbed

Comment: Some more explanation would be good, e.g. just an example xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use GridView 
You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261088/gridview-with-two-columns-and-auto-resized-images) or [this](http://www.technotalkative.com/?s=Grid+View).