# Android: error when creating an array of items

Tags: android, gridview

I following the answer in this topic
[Gridview with two columns and auto resized images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261088/gridview-with-two-columns-and-auto-resized-images)

But, I get error at this line

```
items.add(new Item("Red", R.drawable.red));
```

The cause is the requirement of 2nd params is a `String`. But, `R.drawable.red` is `integer`.

So, anyone can teach me solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: @DenisKulygin IDE (eclipse) suggest: 1.Remove argument to match Item(CharSequence)' 2.Change type of 'red' to 'String'

Comment: In your example defined 'Item' class, where you define this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your custom **`Item`** class, which has the following constructor.

```
class Item {
    Item(String str, int id) {
    ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. sorry all because this stupid question, I come back to programming for a long time not touching

Comment: Don't apologize. Happens to all of us. Glad I could be of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

If 2nd param's type is String just convert the id to a string:

```
items.add(new Item("Red", String.valueOf(R.drawable.red)));
```

Later you can convert to integer with `Integer.valueOf(str);`

However you should change the class constructors parameter type to int as the other answer suggested. You wouldn't need to convert at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but reviewing the topic you posted, the 2nd parameter in the **Item** class is **int** not **String**

Comment: yes, in that topic the 2nd param is Int, but I use default Item in android the method add require 2nd param is String. I am trying to create a class Item as Swayam suggested

Answer (score 0):

You want to change second param is string? In your link sample code **MyAdapter Class**  have modal class **Item** you need to change like that.

```
private class Item {
        final String name;
        final String drawableId;

    Item(String name, String drawableId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.drawableId = drawableId;
    }
}
```