# Android Studio Layout for 4 images

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm having some issues with laying out an activity layout in xml, well I'm using the Design option and the layout is shown in xml below, which is all embedded in a RelativeLayout.

Basically, what I want to have is four even ImageViews which I'll be adding images too, for a Quiz and there are 4 squares, two on top and two on bottom which altogether will make a larger square.

What I have is ok, but I think there should be a better or standard way or laying out stuff like this with Android?

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="89dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView" />
```

Comment: What about using a `GridView` for this?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work as I require, thanks anyways Rami.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using the LinearLayouts, each with 2 ImageViews, nested within a parent LinearLayout for the actual form. The parent LinearLayout has the orientation="vertical" and the nested LinearLayout="horizontal".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `GridView` for the layout of your images and I think you can use `layout_weight` and `weightSum` to avoid having to set a definite size for your images and worrying about it not working properly on different screen sizes. That and the worry of images overlapping.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261088/gridview-with-two-columns-and-auto-resized-images) an SO question that covers using a two column gridview for images as well, I'm not sure if this would help you either but since you said two images on top and two on bottom this might still be useful in a way. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean) SO question and the marked answer for a better explanation on what `layout_weight` does and here's a reference for [`weightSum`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum).

Comment: I solved the problem with LinearLayouts, thanks anyways Astatine0936.