# images come off the screen (android, image Views,linear Layouts)

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I want to display multiple images but when the number of images is too big they come off the screen. How can i fix this ? I want if the number of images is too big to go the rest of images on line down according to screen width and height.

To be more specific if I have to display 10 images and the window fits only five whole pictures I want the other rest 5 pictures to be displayed in the next line and so on.

```
for(int i=0;i<value1;i++){

            image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            image.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) );

            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            linear1.addView(image);

        }
```

Comment: Does this question / its answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261088/gridview-with-two-columns-and-auto-resized-images