# Collection View in Android

Tags: android

I have been following the following tutorial [Gridview with two columns and auto resized images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261088/gridview-with-two-columns-and-auto-resized-images) and coded as follows and get red highlighted errors. I have fixed several errors, but could not able to figure out the followings

[image]

In detail in Line 37, I am getting the following errors:

[image]

Comment: What is `R.drawable`?

Comment: it is resources folder, oh ok I have got you mean. I should put images there. Do you have any idea regarding line 37-40 errors

Comment: R.drawable.red is lable ? did you check they are exist in the drawable folder ? are you developing for multiple resolutions ? if so can you please give us the folder details and what are the images exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extending BaseAdapter. your ProductHomeActivity class must extend Activity class.