# Display unknown amount of images

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a layout that will display images without knowing how many. First i thought of a ScrollView, but don't know how to add *different* images to it. How can that be done? Or is there any other solution?

Comment: Post relevant code whatever you tried.

Comment: A scrollview allows you to touch the screen and scroll if there is more content then there is space on the page. Inside you can have an ImageView, textview, edittext, so on.. It is not specific to images

Answer (score 1):

> How can that be done?

Have the `ScrollView` wrap around a `vertical` `LinearLayout`, into which you add your `ImageView` widgets.

> Or is there any other solution?

`ListView`. `GridView`. `RecyclerView`. `ViewPager`. And so on.

Comment: how do i add unknown number of widgets to LinearLayout?

Comment: @OleksandrZakrevskiy: Create the `ImageView` widget. Configure it (e.g., use Picasso to load your image into it asynchronously). Call `addView()` on the `LinearLayout`, passing it the `ImageView` and a suitable `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. Do this for each image.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to display the images, you can also use GridView : [Grid View Android Developpers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

There is an example : [Gridview with two columns and auto resized images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261088/gridview-with-two-columns-and-auto-resized-images?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `ScrollView` or know the amount of images you're gonna show. Just use a `ListView` with an `ArrayAdapter` that binds a `List` of `Bitmap`s (images) to your `ListView` (each item of your `ListView` is an `ImageView`). Each time you add a new image to your list, just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of your adapter, that's gonna update your `ListView`.

Just google for a relevant tutorial. You're gonna see lots of examples.