# I want to make a GridView for movie posters

Tags: android, android-layout

[The Layout after running the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COKy4.png)I made a GridView with those 2 class and I want to remove space between images in the screenshot, How can remove these white spaces?

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
/>
```

$ImageAdapter Class:

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (view == null){
            imageView=new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(120,120));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        }else {
            imageView = (ImageView) view;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(images[i]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // images
    int [] images={
            R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two,
            R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four,
            /*R.drawable.fastfive, R.drawable.fastsix,
            R.drawable.fastseven*/
    };
}
```

$Movies Class:

```
public class MoviesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you'll get an answer but I would suggest you to user `recyclerview` instead.

Comment: use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261088/gridview-with-two-columns-and-auto-resized-images) link as reference,it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting height width to `120, 120` you should implement like below. Because app will going to run on many different resolution. So its an **Ultimate Solution**.

Width of ImageView to be match_parent and height will be (width of device / 2). It will display square image.

Example

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
width = (width / 2);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,120));
```

Apply this Solution inside `getView` method.

Comment: I can found a getActivity() Method inside the getView method

Comment: getActivity() only if you are in fragment. It should be direct getResources() or yourContext.getActivity() .

Answer (score 0):

If you will combine android:numColumns="auto_fit" and android:stretchMode="columnWidth" will give you a layout that adjusts for different screen sizes. Much better than fixing the number of columns. See below.

you can also use android:numColumns="auto_fit" instead of android:numColumns="3" here to set according to screens.

```
<GridView
      android:id="@+id/GVHomepage"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:numColumns="3" 
      android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
      android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
      android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
      android:background="#edf2f8" />
```

Comment: add your xml in your post.

Comment: Create your custom xml and don't use
imageView=new ImageView(context);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(120,120));
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP); imageView.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
if use want to use above code then use it width device height and width.

try this link : https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to create a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` set to it.

Something like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
public class MoviesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int SPAN_COUNT = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies);

        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, SPAN_COUNT));
        rv.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    }
}
```

---

Adapter items view holder layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this will create a list with grids, with a span count of 2.