# Android flat GridView with buttons

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I need help with creating something like this gird view of buttons:

[image]

I do not know where to start, and also I need to make three rows by two columns grid. I have tried with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15264039/3165402 and this is what I get:
(GridView is scrollable but I do not want that)

[image][image]

Comment: is the grid buttons are fixed it will not change runtime?

Comment: @Pavan Well, when I create adapter, in its constructor I create array of six items

Comment: if you want that 6 items fixed not scroll able but what if it will not fit according to various device size and resolution then there scroll needed, if you want forcefully adjust you can look for https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html