# GridView Item in Center Android

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am trying to set my gridview item in center. You can see in below image that first column have low margin then last column. I want make it in center so it can look good.
[image]

My XML of GirdView is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:textColor="?attr/TextColor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar"
        android:text="Go to Page:"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/appName"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <GridView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/grid_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="5"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/dialog_dismiss"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_dismiss"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar"
        android:text="Dismiss"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="?attr/TextColor"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/appName"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/lblTime"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/lblTime"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and Item XML is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title.Inverse"
            android:textColor="?attr/TextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/appName"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textview_dialogue"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_but_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_but_size"
            android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if someone can help me for come out from issue. Thanks

Comment: Try `layout_width="wrap_content"` for gridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### try this. hope it will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
     android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:textColor="?attr/TextColor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar"
    android:text="Go to Page:"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/appName"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:padding="8dp" />

<GridView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/grid_dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"        
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/dialog_dismiss"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_dismiss"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar"
    android:text="Dismiss"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="?attr/TextColor"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/appName"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/lblTime"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/lblTime"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an existing answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261088/gridview-with-two-columns-and-auto-resized-images?answertab=oldest#tab-top). Hope it helps.

So the first thing you should enable **"Show layout bound"**([see here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGqJhK0FTjw)) so that you are able to see the detail of your layout as the image below. It helps you to correct you layout easily:

[image]